# Trigger input[type=file] via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to trigger the click event of an `<input type="file" />` via javascript (onclick the file selection dialogue should open).  So far I've tried:

```
$('#uploadFile').trigger('click')
.trigger('submit')
.submit()
.post(); // Stacked for brevity
```

No dice.

Is there something special about this input that prevents these approaches from working?

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9eU8P/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

some of the default actions of events are prevented by the browser if the event is triggered by a script and is not done in a user initialized thread for security reasons.

See it working if it is triggered from a another click handler(User has to click the button)

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#uploadFile').trigger('click')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcpV2/4/)

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.  Any comments on cross-browser support?

Comment: @monners it should be fine if you don't have a on change handler in the file input where you submit a form

Comment: that's a good point, and that might be an issue, but this is more than enough to get me started.  Thanks @ArunPJohny

Comment: Instead of this script, you can also use `<label for="uploadFile">this</label>` to trigger the file button on click.